# Is this bass tab wrong?

Tags: ear-training, tablature

The following tab seems to have a mistake or typo (circled in red, with the way I play it in green below):

[image]

Am I right that what is shown as F (D string, fret 3) should really be played as an F#/Gb (D string, fret 4)?

Comment: "Yes, the tab is wrong. The tab is always wrong. What are we talking about?"

Comment: @DaveJacoby - please make sense of your comment. Tabs are not *always* wrong. *Often*, but not always!

Comment: Well, if it is supposed to be B major then this F# is what you’d expect.

Comment: I don't _think_ I can put a ROTFL emoji here. Can I?  

Comment: The stave is also wrong. It should show the key signature of E major, 4 sharps, instead of accidentals everywhere, and it also omits the # on the Fs. Very poor quality work all round.

Comment: @user207421 So you’re telling me it’s NOT a B(b5) chord there?  Man, I’ve been playing it wrong all these years! 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your way is certainly how I've ever played it! The 1-3-5 of a B chord will surely have F♯ as its 5th, which is shown in the real dots as F♮, which is probably where the mistake started. Just listened to the track, and it seems (although the bassline is a bit muffled) that we're right, and the tab (and dots) are wrong!

If the key signature had been used (It's in E major), that would have included F♯.

Answer (score 4):

You're correct: it's a mistake in the music. The note should be F-sharp.